# Error in CORS Ajax request although CORS headers are ok and I get the POST response

Tags: ajax, cors

I am trying to make an Ajax CORS request using this jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/itt_service/rest",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: pdata,
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data){})
      .always(function (a,data,b) {})
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Failed: " + errorThrown);});
```

but the fail function is always executed with no further explanation.
Looking at the Network section of the browser I can see that there is first an OPTIONS preflight request as expected.
The request headers are:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8383
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

and the response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2018 10:19:30 GMT
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
```

Everything looks ok, and it must be, because this preflight request is followed by the actual POST request. The request headers now are

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 79
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8383
Referer: http://localhost:8383/itt_webclient/main.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
```

and the response headers are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2018 10:19:30 GMT
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
```

Everything looks ok again. I get 200 OK, I get the correct Content-Length (27), and I can even see the response body at the Network tool of the browser:

```
{"results":{},"errors":[8]}
```

(don't mind about the "errors" response at the body, it's the expected correct response)
BUT the done handler is never called. Instead the fail handler is always called with "textStatus":"error" and "errorThrown":"".
The CORS section looks ok to me, and I guess that if the cors negotiation failed, the second POST request would not take place at all. I could also check that, by changing the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response from the server to something "wrong", which resulted in no POST request as expected.
I was wondering if the JSON response was somehow not well formed, so I also changed the expected response type (both at the client and at the server) to "text/plain", but the problem remained.
I also tried to make the request using XMLHttpRequest and not jQuery, with the same results.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: The server (Glassfish?) apparently isn’t adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to the response for the POST request — it’s only adding it to the response for the OPTIONS request. But the server needs to send it for the response to the POST request also. Even though the browser gets the response for the POST and you can see that response in devtools, the browser will block your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the response unless it includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. I added the Access-Control headers also to the POST response and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing `dataType`  or try changing it to some other options(maybe jsonp) given here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/